# How to run docker-compose file with intellij AND see container logs?

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, webstorm

I have successfully set up `docker-compose` to run inside IntelliJ, but when I run the configuration, IntelliJ starts the docker-compose containers, but won't show any logs - even though the container is running properly.

I have set up docker-compose in various other Jetbrains IDEs, and access logs have been visible. What am I doing wrong?[image]

[image]

Comment: And whey you try `docker-compose logs` from console do you see anything?

Comment: which version of Intellij IDEA do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can certainly use the `docker-compose logs` command mentioned in the comments on the OP's question, there's a better way.  At least there is at the time I'm answering, though perhaps not 2 years ago when originally asked.

In any case, if you look at the run job's configuration, you will probably see an option tag named `attach: none`.  You just need to click on the tag's `X` icon to remove it, as highlighted below.

[image]
That will cause the logs to be displayed in the same window as the Docker service.

If, however, you wanted to see just one (or more) of the services in your compose file, you could click on the `Modify` button in the "docker-compose up" heading and add an `Attach` option with the specific service(s) you wanted.

Now you can see exactly what you want.

This particular example was done on JetBrains' WebStorm IDE, but recent IntelliJ versions should prove no different.